# 'readonly' exit status in bash

Tags: bash

I'm trying to assign output of command to variable and capture the status. It works as expected:

```
$ foo=$(false); echo $?
1
```

until I'm trying to make readonly variable:

```
$ readonly foo=$(false); echo $?
0
```

I know I can have temporary rw variable then assign it to ro variable, but I'm quite disappointed. ;) Is there more elegant way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in two steps without needing a temporary variable:

```
foo="$(false)"
echo $?
readonly foo
```

Alternatively you can do

```
readonly foo="$(false)" status="$?"
```

to capture both the output and the exit status simultaneously.

Answer (score 2):

`readonly`, like `local` and `declare`, is itself a command, with its own exit status.

Thus, you should run these commands *separately* from the assignments whose exit status you want to capture, to avoid collecting the exit status of the `readonly` command. In this case:

```
foo=$(something); foo_retval=$?
readonly foo
```

This is a variant on the common practice of defining variables in a function local *first*, before assigning values to them.